# Add missing records to result table records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following issue: I have two tables

```
Article
id     state
Guid    int
```

and

```
Article_history
id   state   datechange
Guid  int     datetime
```

First table store porduct information, second fills then product state changed. E.g.

```
Article
id     state
1       1

Article_history
id   state   datechange
1     1      2019-11-10
1     2      2020-01-15
```

I need to create a report for each article in several years period with one month step:

```
date         id   state
2019-11-01   1    1
2019-12-01   1    1 --There is my problem
2020-01-01   1    2
```

I create a query to `Article_history` table, but since my app create record only on change `Article state` not every month is presented in `Article_history`. In my example I actualy don't have record for 2019-12-01. I need to fill the time gaps for each product with the last known state.

I can't think about method to fill this gaps withot using cursor for each month in the given period but it takes to much time.
Please, give me advice.

Mock

```
 Create TABLE Article
(
    id int,
    state int
)

Create TABLE Article_history
(
    id int,
    datechange datetime,
    state int
)

Insert into Article (id, state)
VALUES (1,1)
,(2,1)
,(3,2)

INSERT into Article_history (id, datechange, state)
VALUES (1,'2019-11-10',1)
,(1,'2020-01-15',2);
```

My query:

```
 With theDates As
(
    Select DATEFROMPARTS(2019,11,1) as theDate
    Union All
    Select DateAdd(MONTH,1,theDate)
    From theDates
    Where DATEADD(MONTH,1,theDate)<=GETDATE()
)
Select 
    Convert(date,dt.theDate,104) as 'date'
    ,arth.id
    ,arth.state
From theDates as dt
left join Article_history as arth
on arth.datechange>=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dt.theDate), 0) and arth.datechange<=EOMONTH(dt.theDate)
Option (Maxrecursion 0)
```

My Result:

```
date         id   state
2019-11-01   1    1
2020-01-01   1    2
```

I want to get

```
 date         id   state
 2019-11-01   1    1
 2019-12-01   1    1 
 2020-01-01   1    2
```

December is missing

To clarify my problem: record from `Article` can be not in `Article_history` at all, if so I want to put this record in every month with some default values.

UPD: `Article` table have around 3k records. PR id in `Article` is a FK for `Article_history`. I need to create a representation for **each** record in `Article`. In pseudo code:

```
foreach article in Article {
  foreach month in TheDates {
    if(article.id not in result where result.month = month) {
      AddInResult(new [result.month=month, result.id=article.id, result.state = GetLastStateFromArticleHistory(article.id,month)]
    }
 }}
```

I have a result table with history, but not all `Article` represented for each month. I need to add this records with the last available status for which from `Article_history`.

Answer (score 3):

First, good job on providing a minimal example and create scripts. 
Also, good job on having already constructed the tally table needed- many ways around, a cte is just fine.

Now, your result does not match mine. I get a third column with id and state NULLS for december. Maybe you actually ran an inner join?

```
With theDates As
(
    Select DATEFROMPARTS(2019,11,1) as theDate
    Union All
    Select DateAdd(MONTH,1,theDate)
    From theDates
    Where DATEADD(MONTH,1,theDate)<=GETDATE()
)
Select 
    Convert(date,dt.theDate,104) as 'date'
    ,a.id
    ,lastone.*
From theDates as dt
cross join Article a -- cartesian product of dates * articles
outer apply
(
    select top 1 state
    from Article_history as arth
    where 
        arth.datechange<EOMONTH(dt.theDate)
        and a.id=arth.id
    order by arth.datechange desc
) as lastone
order by id,dt.theDate

Result:

+------------+----+-------+
|    date    | id | state |
+------------+----+-------+
| 2019-11-01 |  1 | 1     |
| 2019-12-01 |  1 | 1     |
| 2020-01-01 |  1 | 2     |
| 2019-11-01 |  2 | NULL  |
| 2019-12-01 |  2 | NULL  |
| 2020-01-01 |  2 | NULL  |
| 2019-11-01 |  3 | NULL  |
| 2019-12-01 |  3 | NULL  |
| 2020-01-01 |  3 | NULL  |
+------------+----+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer and kind words. But your solution is not exactly what I'm looking for. I have updated my question.

Comment: I have only 3 records in result one for each month in TheDates https://pastebin.com/hfSjEpZB

Comment: I've edited the answer to include all articles, check it out

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I'm looking for.